# How to instantiate and use class in same line

Tags: vb.net, porting

I have a simple line in C# that I'm trying to translate to VB.NET and I'm getting nowhere.

```
(new CMachine()).Init();
```

Yes, It needs to be a 1-liner because the point I'm trying to demonstrate is that an instance of `CMachine` need not stick around after `Init()` has been called. Later in the code, I demonstrate subsequent instances of `CMachine` have already been initialized.

FYI: `New CMachine().Init()` and `(New CMachine()).Init()` do not work.

Comment: In what way does it not "*work*"?

Comment: Side note: "Later in the code, I demonstrate subsequent instances of CMachine have already been initialized." probably is unrelated to you post at all... at least it feels very confusing - how instance method impacts other instances (unless you want to demonstrate some dirty hacks...)... Note that this question may be more suitable for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I agree it's a confusing implementation. And that's part of what I'm demonstrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more idiomatic way of doing this, but this works:

```
With New CMachine
    .Init()
End With
```

Comment: Perfect. I was so stuck on the idea of 1-liner that I missed other ways of showing it.